# Silly question about zero

Tags: arithmetic, operations-research

First of all, please don't think bad of this question. And i'm really sorry for this stupid question.

We know $\dfrac 0 0$ is not a number, undefined, undetermined, meaningless or whatever.
I just want to know, if i multiply this expression by $0$, could it gives me the answer $0$?

I mean :

$$\frac{0}{0}\times 0=0$$ by inverse multiplication

> The reason i'm asking this question, because i found this problem when
>   i was calculating project time, project cost on project planning involving the PERT/CPM.

Just to the point, i will take one activity that makes me confused.

given :

1. Normal Time $=1$
2. Normal Cost $=5$
3. Crash Time $=1$
4. Crash Cost $=5$
5. Time Reduction $0$

The formula of Slope is
$$\Delta C=\frac{\text{Crash Cost $-$ Normal Cost}}{\text{Normal Time $-$ Crash Time}}$$

Hence, we obtain

$$\frac{5-5}{1-1}=\frac 0 0$$

My goal is calculating The Optimal Cost, i can't show all the result, because there are too many numbers and tables. (Sorry)

But, with CPM (Critical Path Method using Network Graph), i found the optimal cost for that activity must be five, and this referring to my $\Delta C$. And i'm sure it must be five because I'm very careful when calculating it.

Then, when i use the fact of the optimal cost formula that is:

Optimal Cost $=$ Normal Cost $+$ (slope ($\Delta C$) $\times$ Time Reduction)

We have :

Optimal Cost $=5+\dfrac{0}{0}\times 0$

Since with CPM my activity is five, the term $\dfrac{0}{0}\times 0$ *must be* $0$

It's weird, does $0$ has multiplication inverse?

It looks like againts the rule. Please give me the reason about, how does this is make sense?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Every number multiplied by $0$ gives $0$; the issue is : is $\dfrac 0 0$ a number ?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think that is a number.

Comment: The formula for slope doesn't make sense if Normal Time = Crash Time.  Probably the optimal cost should just set equal to the normal cost in that case.

Comment: Exactly ! The formula $\dfrac 0 0$ is *undefined* because is a formula that does not outputs a number. Thus, we cannot use it in normal arithmetical operations.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: undefined or undetermined?